# How to set aws "MemoryUtilization" alarm for ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, memory, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to setup an alarm on my ec2 instance for "Memory Utilization" through aws-cli.
The command that I am using to do this is:

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-data \
--metric-name MemoryUtilization \
--dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=$val \
--statistic Average \
--namespace AWS/ECS \
--unit Percent
```

where, $val is my ec2 InstanceId. **The error I get is:**

```
not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

And when I try using this code:

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-data \
--metric-name MemoryUtilization \
--dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=$val \
--statistic Average \
--namespace AWS/ECS \
--unit Percent \  
--period $period \
--evaluation-periods 1 \
--threshold $MEMORY_THRESHOLD \
--comparison-operator GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold \
--alarm-actions $arn
```

The error I get is:

```
Unknown options: --evaluation-periods, --threshold, 85, --comparison-operator, GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold, --alarm-actions, arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:539551904532:ec2-monitor, 1
```

Please let me know, how I can create an alarm for my ec2 instance to monitor "Memory Utilization"

Answer (score 2):

For your [put-metric-data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/put-metric-data.html) you need to provide actual values of the metric, using `--value` or `--metric-data`. These options are missing from your call.

In your second attempt you are again using `put-metric-data`, but with incorrect parameters. Please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/put-metric-data.html) for correct parameters of `put-metric-data` call along with examples of its use.

Comment: It worked, I had to just change from put-metric-data to put-metric-alarm as I want to set alarms, thanks for providing detailed info on put-metric-data, it helped.